# Multi Day event in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios6

I want to create an EKevent from objective c, that spans multi-days, in both iOS 5 and iOS 6 the creation process is work as expected, and the event created successfully, but when I fetch the event from an event store the event disappear from  the last day -the day that event ends on - this issue exist in iOS 6.

What do you think guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also saw this issue with multi day events.  I think it's a bug, so I filed a bug report with Apple about it.  I worked around this issue by adjusting my event store predicate for the last day to include 11:59pm of the 2nd-to-last day.  After doing that, I then manually filter out the 2nd-to-last day events, if any were pulled in.